# Rename an Image with MediaStore android

Tags: android, rename, mediastore, android-mediascanner

After renaming images with `file.renameTo(file)` they get grayed in gallery and get unavailable. I tried every kind of Intent for rescanning images with no hope at last, some work on older versions some doesn't worked at all, so I'm trying to update the `MediaStore`, but doesn't sure how to do that right.

Here's some of my codes

This was one of my early approach

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext,
                    filesPath , null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
```

another one

```
private void scanMedia(File file) {

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
}
```

This work on pre 19 but not on kitkat

```
mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

This the MediaStore one

```
int row = mContext.getContentResolver()
                        .update(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        valuesNewFilePath,
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "='" + oldFilePath + "'",
                        null);
```

this method throw this none fatal exception in logcat

---

07-04 02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "media" 07-04    02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):  at    java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124) 07-04 02:37:18.448:    W/MediaProvider(2947):   at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:361) 07-04    02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):    at    java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352) 07-04 02:37:18.448:    W/MediaProvider(2947):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)    07-04 02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):    at    android.content.ContentUris.parseId(ContentUris.java:86) 07-04    02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):    at    com.android.providers.media.MediaThumbRequest.(MediaThumbRequest.java:93)    07-04 02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):     at    com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.requestMediaThumbnail(MediaProvider.java:3742)    07-04 02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):    at    com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.update(MediaProvider.java:4353)    07-04 02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):   at    android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:287)    07-04 02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):  at    android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:215)    07-04 02:37:18.448: W/MediaProvider(2947):    at    android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)

EDIT: I'm sure this can be done. Because when I rename or add some media file, then using the ES File Explorer and changing the path of that media containing folder, they get appear in gallery and added to media store, It takes some time to regenerate thumbnail if you have to much media on that folder. by the way I watch the logcat when I rename an image file: `Media Provider object removed` then some logcat with tag `art` about crating bitmap, I'm sure the only way to do this is updating MediaStore with new data and bitmap. Now how to find and remove the previus data from `MediaStore` and add the new one? If i remove it from MediaStore is it cause to delete that file from the disk?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

This method is working for me on android-21 :

```
public static boolean renameImageFile(Context c, File from, File to) {
    to = getFileWithUnicName(to);
    if (from.renameTo(to)) {
        removeMedia(c, from);
        addMedia(c, to);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void addMedia(Context c, File f) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(f));
    c.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private static void removeMedia(Context c, File f) {
    ContentResolver resolver = c.getContentResolver();
    resolver.delete(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Images.Media.DATA + "=?", new String[] { f.getAbsolutePath() });
}
```

Instead of trying to directly update the image file in the mediastore like you are trying to do in your last attempt, you should try to first remove the old row then add the new row.

Tell me if it solved your problem.

Comment: a little late, but thank you. I had a little concern to removing a media from `MediaStore`, because it actually deletes the image file from the disk storage.

Comment: yes, a little late, maybe this post will help other people on the same problem. BTW it doesn't matter if the image file is removed because we already know that the file renaming operation has been successfull by checking it ;)

Comment: I have a similar problem and I am very confused thanks for the answer I will try! thanks

Comment: @syl80, Your solution is working well. Then how do you think about renaming a folder?